# Custom API for updating products in Strapi returns 405

Tags: node.js, api, axios, controller, strapi

I'm currently setting up Strapi V4 to update products collection with a PUT request after receiving another request from my PIM.

I have just generated a custom API using strapi generate CLI and basically set up two functions to do the above mentioned task within my controller for update-products route.

```
"use strict";

var axios = require("axios");
var qs = require("qs");

function getUpdates() {
  var baseLinkerData = qs.stringify({
    method: "getInventoryProductsList",
    parameters: '{"inventory_id": 3807}',
  });
  var config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php",
    headers: {
      "X-BLToken": `${process.env.BL_TOKEN}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    data: baseLinkerData,
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      // const updates = JSON.stringify(response.data.products);
      const updates = response.data.products;
      // console.log(updates);
      updateProducts(updates);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

function updateProducts(productList) {
  // Prepare a request

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(productList)) {

    // Mapping of the product data
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      data: {
        id: value.id,
        ean: value.ean ? value.ean : null,
        sku: value.sku ? value.sku : null,
        name: value.name,
        quantity: value.stock ? parseInt(value.stock.bl_5076) : 0,
        price_brutto: value.prices ? parseFloat(value.prices["3624"]) : 0,
      },
    });
    console.log(data);

   // Config for the request
    var config = {
      method: "put",
      url: `${process.env.MY_HEROKU_URL}/api/products/${key}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: process.env.STRAPI_API_AUTH,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: data,
    };

    // Send the request

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    // });
  }
}
/**
 * A set of functions called "actions" for `update-products`
 */

module.exports = {
  exampleAction: async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
      getUpdates();
      ctx.body = "ok";
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.body = err;
    }
  },
};
```

**With this code I am getting the 405 error:**

```
Error: connect EMFILE 00.000.00.000:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
    at internalConnect (net.js:934:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:452:18)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1077:9)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:73:8) {
  errno: -24,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '00.000.00.000',
  port: 443,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'process.env.BEARER',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.24.0',
      'Content-Length': 82
    },
    method: 'put',
    url: 'https://sampleurl.herokuapp.com/api/products/16611',
    data: '{"data":{"id":21847637,"ean":null,"sku":null,"name":"GRA O TRON Winter is here – Kubek termiczny","quantity":1,"price_brutto":55.99}}'
    },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'https:',
      path: '/api/products/16611',
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'sampleurl.herokuapp.com',
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/api/products/16611'
    },
    _ended: false,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 82,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'PUT /api/products/16611 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'Author^Cse,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'sampleurl.herokuapp.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://sampleurl.herokuapp.com/api/products/16611',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

I just can't wrap my head around this, also I was wondering what would be another way to update the collection without using API when the data is already pulled with the first request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it by using these two calls - depending on my control hash value and if product exists or not.

```
await strapi.db.query('api::product.product').update(query)
await strapi.db.query('api::product.product').create(query)
```

The queries for update and create are the same - but the create one does not have “where” parameter.

```
const query = {
  where: {
    id: existing_products[new_data.import_code].id
  },
  data: {
    ...new_data,
    import_date_time: new Date().toISOString(),
    import_hash: hash
  }
}
```

Also - notice the hash value - I calculate it from “new_data” and import only if they are different - so I do not have to update the record if nothing has changed.